# Wireless keyboard/mouse works in BIOS but not in Windows

Tags: keyboard, bios, mouse

Like the title says, my Logitech EX100 Wireless M/KB work fine in BIOS, but as soon as Windows starts they stop working.

I have a wired mouse and a wired keyboard plugged in as well, and they work both in BIOS and Windows (so in BIOS I can use both mice and both keyboards - but only the wired ones in Windows).

I have tried several different USB ports, I've tried unplugging the wired M/KB and I've tried plugging the Wireless receiver into another computer (with Ubuntu - where it worked fine immediately).

What gives??

Comment: did you install the software for the devices?

Comment: There is no software for it. No drivers. The only thing I found was the SitePoint app (http://www.logitech.com/sv-se/support/4334?osid=14&bit=64) which does nothing to help the problem. It works fine in Ubuntu and BIOS without any drivers so.